# How modular arithmetic helps in finding no. of possible solutions of an equation.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I was going through a question "No. positive perfect cubes less than 1000 that are the sum of the cubes of two positive integers."

And found this as the answer :

*The only cubic residues mod $7$ are $0$ and $±1$. So if $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$, either
$c=7$ and $a=3,5$ or $6$ (the positive integers less than $7$ whose cubes are $-1$ mod $7$).
$a=7$.
That's $3+9=12$ cases*

I don't understand how modular arithmetic used to find no. of solutions (cases).

Answer (score 1):

> The only cubic residues mod $7$ are $0$ and $\pm 1$.

The cubic residues in various moduli are:

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}x&x^3&x^3&x^3&x^3&x^3\\ & \pmod8&\pmod 7&\pmod6&\pmod5&\pmod4\\\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1\\2&0&1&2&3&0\\3&1&-1&3&2&1\\4&0&1&4&4\\5&1&-1&5\\6&0&-1\\7&1
\end{array}$

So when we look at the equation $a^3+b^3 = c^3$ modulo $7$, it can only be one of $$\begin{array}{lrcrcrl}
&a^3&&b^3&&c^3\\
\hline
\text{case 1.}& 0&+&0&\equiv&0&\pmod 7\\
\text{case 2.}& -1&+&1&\equiv&0&\pmod 7\\
\text{case 3.}& 0&+&1&\equiv&1&\pmod 7\\
\text{case 4.}& 0&-&1&\equiv&-1&\pmod 7\\\end{array}$$

(We can't have cases like $a^3\equiv b^3\equiv1$ because that would require $c^3\equiv2$, which has no solutions, so apart from swapping $a$ and $b$, which would give the same solutions, these are the only possibilities.)

In each case, there is at least one number whose cube is $0\pmod 7$. $7^3=343$ and $14^3=2744$, so the only candidate under $1000$ is $7$. Since $10^3=1000$ we must have $1\le a,b \le 9$ and $1\le c \le 10$.

We can't have $7^3+7^3=7^3$ so case $1$ is ruled out.

> either $c=7$ and $a=3,5$ or $6$ (the positive integers less than $7$ whose cubes are $−1$ mod $7$)

For case $2$, we must have $c=7$ and $a\in\{3,5,6\}$ , which is $3$ sub-cases to check.

> $a=7$

For case $3$, we must have $a=7$ and $b\in\{1,2,4,8,9\}$, which is $5$ sub-cases to check.

For case $4$, we must have $a=7$ and $b\in\{3,5,6\}$, which is $3$ sub-cases to check. You could also interpret case $4$ as $a=7$ and $c\in\{3,4,6,10\}$, which would give $4$ sub-cases to check.

Using modulo arithmetic shrinks the problem down to checking $11$ or $12$ possibilities.

So, why choose modulo $7$?  Well, modulo $3$, $5$, $6$ and $10$ you get all the residues as cubes, so that doesn't narrow the cases very much. Modulo $4$ and $8$ each give $3$ equations, but there are a lot of sub-cases, so more work at the end.

Modulo $7$ just works out nice. A deeper answer might use that for a prime $p\equiv1\pmod3$ you get $\frac{p-1}3$ non-zero cubic residues; for a prime $p\equiv2\pmod3$ you get $p-1$ (i.e. lots of) non-zero cubic residues.  If you were dealing with $5$th powers, modulo $11=2\times5+1$ would be good; in general for $n$-th powers, $2n+1$ is a good choice if it is prime.

Comment: My question is exactly about how we figure out we have to use modulo 7 not any other number. ?

Comment: @user292174: You didn't say that in your question :-).  I've added some discussion on why mod $7$.